# Memory Consumption is always increasing in Humble-Video

Tags: java, video, memory-leaks, ffmpeg, java-native-interface

I have been using [humble-video](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video) in a live streaming project to convert flv to mp4. I've realized that java process's(in which humble-video codes are running) memory usage is always increasing when looking with top command.

After that I changed the demo source code of the humble-video and put the [segmentFile function](https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video/blob/master/humble-video-demos/src/main/java/io/humble/video/demos/ContainerSegmenter.java#L212) in an infinite loop and memory usage of the process is again always increasing when looking with top command. It is over 2.5GiB and has been running for about 30 mins.

I expect the process's memory consumption to stay stable somewhere between 40-50MB not to keep increasing always.

Do you have any idea about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the problem.

The problem is Garbage Collector does not clear WeakReferences so that JNIMemoryManager does not delete native objects. Calling System.gc() after every iteration is helping but it is not the exact solution.

The solution is that calling delete() at the end of each iteration. Some objects are created which you may not expect during the execution so please look at which objects are created with `JNIMemoryManager.getMgr().dumpMemoryLog();` and look at how many objects are alive with  `JNIMemoryManager.getMgr().getNumPinnedObjects();`

The last state of the segmentFile function is as below and memory consumption still stays about 80 MiB at the end of 15min.

```
 private void segmentFile(String input, String output, int hls_start,
      int hls_time, int hls_list_size, int hls_wrap, String hls_base_url,
      String vFilter,
      String aFilter) throws InterruptedException, IOException {

    JNIMemoryManager.getMgr().setMemoryDebugging(true);


    Demuxer demuxer = Demuxer.make();

    demuxer.open(input, null, false, true, null, null);

    // we're forcing this to be HTTP Live Streaming for this demo.
    Muxer muxer = Muxer.make(output, null, "hls");
    muxer.setProperty("start_number", hls_start);
    muxer.setProperty("hls_time", hls_time);
    muxer.setProperty("hls_list_size", hls_list_size);
    muxer.setProperty("hls_wrap", hls_wrap);
    if (hls_base_url != null && hls_base_url.length() > 0)
      muxer.setProperty("hls_base_url", hls_base_url);

    MuxerFormat format = MuxerFormat.guessFormat("mp4", null, null);

    /**
     * Create bit stream filters if we are asked to.
     */
    BitStreamFilter vf = vFilter != null ? BitStreamFilter.make(vFilter) : null;
    BitStreamFilter af = aFilter != null ? BitStreamFilter.make(aFilter) : null;

    int n = demuxer.getNumStreams();
    DemuxerStream[] demuxerStreams = new DemuxerStream[n];
    Decoder[] decoders = new Decoder[n];
    List<MuxerStream> muxerStreamList = new ArrayList();
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      demuxerStreams[i] = demuxer.getStream(i);
      decoders[i] = demuxerStreams[i].getDecoder();
      Decoder d = decoders[i];

      if (d != null) {
        // neat; we can decode. Now let's see if this decoder can fit into the mp4 format.
        if (!format.getSupportedCodecs().contains(d.getCodecID())) {
          throw new RuntimeException("Input filename (" + input + ") contains at least one stream with a codec not supported in the output format: " + d.toString());
        }
        if (format.getFlag(MuxerFormat.Flag.GLOBAL_HEADER))
          d.setFlag(Coder.Flag.FLAG_GLOBAL_HEADER, true);
        d.open(null, null);
        muxerStreamList.add(muxer.addNewStream(d));
      }
    }
    muxer.open(null, null);

    n = muxer.getNumStreams();
    MuxerStream[] muxerStreams = new MuxerStream[n];
    Coder[] coder = new Coder[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        muxerStreams[i] = muxer.getStream(i);
        if (muxerStreams[i] != null) {
            coder[i] = muxerStreams[i].getCoder();
        }
    }

    MediaPacket packet = MediaPacket.make();

    while(demuxer.read(packet) >= 0) {
      /**
       * Now we have a packet, but we can only write packets that had decoders we knew what to do with.
       */
      final Decoder d = decoders[packet.getStreamIndex()];
      if (packet.isComplete() && d != null) {
        // check to see if we are using bit stream filters, and if so, filter the audio
        // or video.
        if (vf != null && d.getCodecType() == Type.MEDIA_VIDEO)
          vf.filter(packet, null);
        else if (af != null && d.getCodecType() == Type.MEDIA_AUDIO)
          af.filter(packet, null);

        muxer.write(packet, false);

      }
    }



    // It is good practice to close demuxers when you're done to free
    // up file handles. Humble will EVENTUALLY detect if nothing else
    // references this demuxer and close it then, but get in the habit
    // of cleaning up after yourself, and your future girlfriend/boyfriend
    // will appreciate it.

    muxer.close();
    demuxer.close();

    muxer.delete();
    demuxer.delete();
    packet.delete();
    format.delete();
    vf.delete();

    muxer = null;
    demuxer = null;
    packet = null;
    format = null;
    vf = null;

    for (int i=0; i < muxerStreams.length; i++) {
        if (muxerStreams[i] != null) {
            muxerStreams[i].delete();
            muxerStreams[i] = null;
        }
        if (coder[i] != null) {
            coder[i].delete();
            coder[i] = null;
        }
    }

    for (int i=0; i < demuxerStreams.length; i++) {
        if (demuxerStreams[i] != null) {
            demuxerStreams[i].delete();
            demuxerStreams[i] = null;
        }
        if (decoders[i] != null) {
            decoders[i].delete();
            decoders[i] = null;
        }
    }

    for (Iterator iterator = muxerStreamList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        MuxerStream muxerStream = (MuxerStream) iterator.next();
        if (muxerStream != null) {
            muxerStream.delete();
            muxerStream = null;
        }
    }
    muxerStreamList.clear();
    muxerStreamList = null;

    System.out.println("number of alive objects:" + JNIMemoryManager.getMgr().getNumPinnedObjects());


  }
```

Comment: For future reference, Humble Video has a facility that will start a thread to force collections (but does not start it by default). See: `io.humble.ferry.JNIMemoryManager.startCollectionThread()`